# When and how can I change the conclusion in rules of inference

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus

I have seen people changing the conclusion of the examples in the rules of inference. My question is when I'm able to do that? If I have to prove P and Q which one should I choose?

Examples 1:
premises { p → q, p ∨ q } conclusion/prove q ∨ r
But they are making it, just prove q but they add ¬r in the premises so we have

Final:
Premises { p → q, p ∨ q, ¬r } conslusion q

Example 2:

Premises { p ∨ q, ¬q ∨ r, r → s} conclusion: ¬p → s

Final:
they change it to { p ∨ q, ¬q ∨ r, r → s, ¬p } conclusion s

Can I simplify this every time?

Comment: In the first case, if $r$ is true then $q\lor r$ is true and there is nothing to prove. Therefore, we suppose $\lnot r$ is true. In the second case, we want to prove $\lnot p\to s$ so we suppose $\lnot p$ is true.

Comment: Premises do not change.

Comment: "changing the conclusion of the examples in the rules of inference" ??? A rule is a "recipe" for building inferences. You have to use it producing suitable instances of it according to the premises you have.

Answer (score 1):

Both examples above are simple application of the [Deduction Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deduction_theorem) :

> in order to prove $Γ ⊢ p → q$, prove $Γ,p ⊢ q$.

Also the first one is based on the DT, with the "trick" of using the [Material Implication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Material_implication_(rule_of_inference)) rule :

> $q∨r$ is equivalent to : $¬ r → q$.

Thus, the proof is :

1) $p → q, p ∨ q, ¬r \vdash q$ --- given

2) $p → q, p ∨ q \vdash ¬r \to q$ --- from 1) by DT

> 3) $p → q, p ∨ q \vdash r \lor q$ --- from 2) by Material Implication.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a proof of the first example:

[image]

Note that it doesn't matter if one adds $\neg R$ to the premises. One can still derive $Q$ or $Q \lor R$ with or without that premise.

---

Here is a proof of the second example:

[image]

If one also assumed $\neg P$ as a premise the proof might look like this:

[image]

In this example, unlike the first example, one could make use of the additional premise. However, what one is asked to prove has changed as well. It is no longer a conditional, $\neg P \to S$, but the proposition $S$.

Regardless, the two examples do not illustrate a similar pattern. Given premises and a desired goal, one should use only defined inference rules to reach the goal from the premises.

---

Kevin Klement's JavaScript/PHP Fitch-style natural deduction proof editor and checker http://proofs.openlogicproject.org/